# reduce javascript code (stack overflow 2022)

Tags: javascript, html, css, puzzle

I'm doing this puzzle, and sometimes when I give a new game the pieces go wrong, I added a function for it and from what I see it doesn't work, my head can't take it anymore. And I would also like to simplify the code a bit, that's why I asked before.

```js
var recuento = 0;
var movimientos = 0;

var CheckArray = new Array(9);

function swapTiles(cell1, cell2) {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById(cell1),
    elem2 = document.getElementById(cell2);

  var tempClass = elem1.className;
  var tempText = elem1.textContent;

  elem1.className = elem2.className;

  elem1.textContent = elem2.textContent;
  elem2.className = tempClass;
  elem2.textContent = tempText;
}


function shuffle() {
  for (var row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {
    for (var column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {
      var row2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
      var column2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

      swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + row2 + column2);
    }
  }
  Check();
}

function Check() {
  CheckArray[0] = document.getElementById("cell11").getAttribute('class');
  CheckArray[1] = document.getElementById("cell12").getAttribute('class');
  CheckArray[2] = document.getElementById("cell13").getAttribute('class');
  CheckArray[3] = document.getElementById("cell21").getAttribute('class');
  CheckArray[4] = document.getElementById("cell22").getAttribute('class');
  CheckArray[5] = document.getElementById("cell23").getAttribute('class');
  CheckArray[6] = document.getElementById("cell31").getAttribute('class');
  CheckArray[7] = document.getElementById("cell32").getAttribute('class');
  for (var x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    CheckArray[x] = CheckArray[x].replaceAll('title', '');
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < CheckArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (CheckArray[j] > CheckArray[j + 1]) {
        let aux = CheckArray[j];
        CheckArray[j] = CheckArray[j + 1];
        CheckArray[j + 1] = aux;
        movimientos++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (movimientos % 2 == 0) {} else {
    alert("No es pot resoldre");
  }
}

function Comprobar() {
  var a = document.getElementById("cell11").getAttribute('class');
  var b = document.getElementById("cell12").getAttribute('class');
  var c = document.getElementById("cell13").getAttribute('class');
  var d = document.getElementById("cell21").getAttribute('class');
  var e = document.getElementById("cell22").getAttribute('class');
  var f = document.getElementById("cell23").getAttribute('class');
  var g = document.getElementById("cell31").getAttribute('class');
  var h = document.getElementById("cell32").getAttribute('class');
  var i = document.getElementById("cell33").getAttribute('class');

  resultado = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = resultado;

  if ((resultado === "tile1tile2tile3tile4tile5tile6tile7tile8tile9") == true) {
    alert("Has guanyat, felicitats!");
  } else {}
}

function clickTile(row, column) {
  var cell = document.getElementById("cell" + row + column);
  var tile = cell.className;
  if (tile != "tile9") {
    if (column < 3) {
      if (document.getElementById("cell" + row + (column + 1)).className == "tile9") {
        swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + row + (column + 1));
        recuento++;
        document.getElementById("control").innerHTML = recuento;
        Comprobar();
        return;
      }
    }
    if (column > 1) {
      if (document.getElementById("cell" + row + (column - 1)).className == "tile9") {
        swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + row + (column - 1));
        recuento++;
        document.getElementById("control").innerHTML = recuento;
        Comprobar();
        return;
      }
    }
    if (row > 1) {
      if (document.getElementById("cell" + (row - 1) + column).className == "tile9") {
        swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + (row - 1) + column);
        recuento++;
        document.getElementById("control").innerHTML = recuento;
        Comprobar();
        return;
      }
    }
    if (row < 3) {
      if (document.getElementById("cell" + (row + 1) + column).className == "tile9") {
        swapTiles("cell" + row + column, "cell" + (row + 1) + column);
        recuento++;
        document.getElementById("control").innerHTML = recuento;
        Comprobar();
        return;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  background: #6ca0e4c4;
}

.tile1,
.tile2,
.tile3,
.tile4,
.tile5,
.tile6,
.tile7,
.tile8,
.tile9 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: url("attacusAtlas.png");
  font-size: 10pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.tile1 {
  background-position: left top;
}

.tile2 {
  background-position: center top;
}

.tile3 {
  background-position: right top;
}

.tile4 {
  background-position: left center;
}

.tile5 {
  background-position: center center;
}

.tile6 {
  background-position: right center;
}

.tile7 {
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.tile8 {
  background-position: center bottom;
}

.tile9 {
  background: white;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="green">Sliding Puzzle.</h1>
<p> Hola, aquest és un <b>puzzle 3x3</b> .</p>
<h2 id="movimientos"></h2>
<h2 id="control"></h2>
<h2 id="test"></h2>

<center>
  <button onClick="shuffle();">New Game</button><br><br>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Seleccionar dificultat</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="3x3.html">Fácil</a>
      <a href="4x4.html">Normal</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="movimientos"></h2>
  <h2 id="control"></h2>
  <h2 id="test"></h2>
  <br><br>

  <div id="table" style="display: table;">
    <div id="row1" style="display: table-row;">
      <div id="cell11" class="tile1" onClick="clickTile(1,1);">1</div>
      <div id="cell12" class="tile2" onClick="clickTile(1,2);">2</div>
      <div id="cell13" class="tile3" onClick="clickTile(1,3);">3</div>


    </div>
    <div id="row2" style="display: table-row;">
      <div id="cell21" class="tile4" onClick="clickTile(2,1);">4</div>
      <div id="cell22" class="tile5" onClick="clickTile(2,2);">5</div>
      <div id="cell23" class="tile6" onClick="clickTile(2,3);">6</div>


    </div>
    <div id="row3" style="display: table-row;">
      <div id="cell31" class="tile7" onClick="clickTile(3,1);">7</div>
      <div id="cell32" class="tile8" onClick="clickTile(3,2);">8</div>
      <div id="cell33" class="tile9" onClick="clickTile(3,3);">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This code isn't even valid JS code. Also, as you are reading none of the variables, the first optimization might be to remove all variables

Comment: As `Comprobar` is empty not, it can also be removed

Comment: Please explain what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this ought to work. Since I don't know what you want to do with the results, I just put them in an array (`cell_classes`).

```
let cell_classes = [];

for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
  for(j = 1; j <= 4; j++){
    const tmp = document.getElementById("cell" + i + "" + j).getAttribute('class');

    cell_classes.push(tmp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. I doubt that the unknown original code, where variables from `a` to `p` were in use, would still work with this change

Comment: If you don't know what the OP wants, it would be better to ask for clarification first

Comment: Also, if you want to help the OP understand what you've changed, it would be good to add some explanation to your answer such that he can learn from the answer